# Form inline not working as expected with React-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to get to grips with [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) and was attempting to replicate a navbar similar to that in [their documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#navbars-overview), but my `Form` component is not displaying as shown in the documentation with the `inline` attribute. My button appears under my form, not sure what the issue is.

Here is the code for my component:

```js
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import FormControl from 'react-bootstrap/FormControl';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

const MyNav = () => (
  <Navbar bg='dark' variant='dark' expand='sm'>
    <Navbar.Brand href='/'>Maths Tips</Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
      <Nav className="mr-auto">
        <Nav.Link href='/'>Home</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href='/rules'>Rules</Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
      <Form inline>
        <FormControl type='text' placeholder='Search' className='mr-sm-2' />
        <Button type='submit'>Search</Button>
      </Form>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>
);

export default MyNav;
```

I have bootstrap imported into my App.scss file, which is then imported into my App.js file where the MyNav component is being rendered.

These are the package versions I'm using that might be relevant:

`"bootstrap": "^5.0.1"`

`"react": "^17.0.2"`

`"react-bootstrap": "^1.6.0"`

Comment: If you have the bootstrap CDN in your application, try and test directly `<Form className="form-check-inline">` instead of `<Form inline>`

Comment: @AlyaKra that did not seem to change anything, would this suggest that bootstrap isn't installed properly?

Comment: I just tried your code and had the same problem. Weird. Try this instead of your Form inline  `<Form className='d-flex'>`. You can add `style={{position:'absolute',right:'0'}}` if you want it on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the issue I suggest replacing `<Form inline>` with `<Form className='d-flex'>` as it will set the display of that section to `flex`.

In addition, if you want to set the search to the far right, add `style={{position:'absolute',right:'0'}}`.

Comment: Using flex breaks the spacing, though. Now my input and button aren't affected by margin and are stuck together. How would you go about adding space between them?

Answer (score 1):

After playing around a bit, I found the issue to be that your Bootstrap package is `v5.0.1`

React Bootstrap is only meant to be used with Bootstrap V4, unfortunately.
Therefore, you may encounter more visual bugs like these. I've found that margins are also slightly bugged when using Bootstrap 5 and React-Bootstrap.

To switch to bootstrap `v4.6.0`, the latest Bootstrap v4 version, execute

`npm i bootstrap@4.6.0` or `yarn add bootstrap@4.6.0`

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround for this, as shared in the comments by @AlyaKra is to change the `<Form inline` to `<Form className='d-flex'>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. The way I was able to solve it was using the latest styles from the CDN by including the link below in my index.html template (React Bootstrap documentation):

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```