# How can I align a search box and button in the navigation bar?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am facing some problems in getting the search text and the search button inline even though I am following a tutorial.

I am using react-bootstrap downloaded using yarn. This is my code in Navigation.js:

```
    return (
        <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Movies</Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>              
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="ml-auto">
                    <Form inline>
                        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
                        <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
                    </Form>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
            </div>
        </Navbar>
    );
```

In my App.js:

```
  return (
        <>
          <Navigation/>
        </>
  );
```

However, the button is always below the search text. Have tried looking through other tutorials but none of the answers fixed the problem. May I check if anyone knows what is wrong here?

[image]

Comment: You need to apply Bootstrap's flex layout. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67674208/form-inline-not-working-as-expected-with-react-bootstrap

Comment: Why do you have those elements in a Collapse component?

Comment: @isherwood It works! Thank you! May I check why is inline not working? I would like to collapse them once the screen is smaller. Will be adding the expand prop